# Multiple coords to one data_vars in xr.dataset

Tags: dataset, data, geospatial

I am trying to create a xarray dataset for a list of events (labeled 1 or 0, so it's an array of integers). To each event three numbers need to be attached - a date, longitude, and latitude.

I provide the date in `coords` for the dimension name "events" using the following code:

```
ds = xr.Dataset(
        data_vars={
            "feature_maps": (
                ("events", "features", "feature_day", "y", "x"),
                feature_output,
            ),
            "event_labels": ("events", label_output),
        },
        coords={"events": time_stamp, "features": ds_coord},
    )
```

I would also like to provide the longitude and latitude of the event. I cannot understand how I can provide also the longitude and latitude to the same dimension name as `coords` so I can do `dataset.sel` both with respect to date, and longitude, latitude.

Comment: Please provide information about the language and framework you are working in. Also note that specific coding questions might be better suitated for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks. I will update the question.